# Java create user lib

Tags: eclipse, java

С генерировал себе кучу .class файлов, как можно правильно запаковать их в одну либу, подключить и использовать?)

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите на утилиту командной строки, идущую вместе с JDK: jar -help

Comment: а побыстрее в eclipse?

Comment: так сразу бы и писали что вы в eclipse. Там есть экспорт проекта в jar.